# How can I ignore/disable INT 01 and INT 03 instructions in the host EXE used to debug my Delphi 6 DLL?

Tags: delphi, debugging, breakpoints, skype

I have a Delphi 6 DirectShow DLL that I am using with Skype.  My debugging setup for the DLL is to set the **Host** parameters for my **Run** parameters to Skype.  The problem is that there appears to be a slew of INT 01 and INT 03 instructions in the Skype client that are making debugging impossible since they are constantly being hit.  Every time one of them is hit the Delphi debugger pops up with an access violation and the CPU window's instruction pointer squarely on the INT 01 or INT 03 instruction.

Is there a way to work around this problem so I can debug properly?  (Note, I recognize it's possible that one of the other external DLLs already loaded by Skype is the problem so it's not Skype, but it's the same problem I need work around in any case).

Comment: Just patch them with NOP opcode

Answer (score 3):

Skype takes a number of extensive measures to defeat debuggers. What you're running into is almost certainly one of them.

You will probably need to debug your DLL in an environment other than Skype.

Comment: To add to duskwuff's above: you might want to add debug output to file and/or using `OutputDebugString` API and watched by DebugView tool in order to get runtime debug output from Skype process without attaching real debugger there.